# Tmux - dynamically split vertically and horizontally based on # of commands?

Tags: tmux

I'm curious to know if there's a way that tmux can dynamically split and adjust windows based on the number of commands you provide.

Currently, this is the way I'm having to do something

```
tmux new-session -d "command"
tmux split-window -h "command"
tmux split-window -v "command"
tmux select-pane -R
tmux split-window -h "command"
```

etc. In the end, it sort of looks a mess and I have to rethink the commands to make sure they're all displaying properly and doesn't look weird.

So after about an hour, I've got it all down manually, but I wanted to know if there was an easier way to go about this. Instead of having a huge box to the left and tons of split windows on the right side, I'd like to have equal sized boxes across the entire terminal.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is the goal here to split a single pane equally in one dimension enough times to run a set of commands one per pane? Resulting in something like: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/3vyejreovlp1uhu/Screenshot%202015-11-08%2022.11.35.png